# Extracting Stone from Image

Tags: computer-vision, image-segmentation, morphological-analysis, mathematical-morphology

Any thoughts on an algorithm to extract the stone from images like this?

[stone http://www.highdesertlapidary.com/media/5/a2079181363c96d4d9c754_s.JPG](http://www.highdesertlapidary.com/media/5/a2079181363c96d4d9c754_s.JPG)

The stones are all different colors.  I need to separate them from both the background and any rulers that might be present.

Thank you.

Comment: I have had some success using global otsu threshhold.  Then selecting the object whose center-of-mass is closest to the center of the image.  However, I believe this requires converting to grayscale.  And this method is failing for stones with similar colors to the background.

Comment: Could you add a few more image examples so that we can have a better idea of the foreground and background distributions of colors ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this, http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html

and then choose a threshold what you desire, it is very good for grouping and segmentation, code is also publicly available.

It may be better if you place the stone on some other surface which is of a different color, may be placing a white sheet below would help(if that is possible)